# P-groups,chain of subgroups of index p

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group. Let $H$ be any subgroup of $G$. How to prove that there exists subgroups of $G$ such that
$$H = H_0 \lt H_1 \lt H_2\lt \cdots \lt H_n=G$$
such that $|H_{i+1}/H_i|=p$?

I have proved the theorem when H is normal subgroup of G, & when H is trivial subgroup.

Here H is any given fixed subgroup to start with (not necessarily normal)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? By the way, for a $p$-group we know the center of $G$ is non-trivial, so that gives you (if the group is non-abelian) a normal subgroup, perhaps that is what you want ; but at first glance I cannot guess what you're actually looking for. And I removed the tag "galois-theory" because this is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

In any $p$-group $G$, "normalizers grow" (if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then $N(H) > H$).

Now take any subgroup of $H$ of $G$.  Since normalizers grow, we have $$H < N(H) < N(N(H)) < \ldots < G$$ which we need to fill in to a "complete" chain, i.e., a chain where the ratio of successive orders is $p$.

By induction on $|G|$, we can fill in the chain between all successive pairs above, except for the last pair. But the second-to-last group is a normal subgroup of $G$ (since its normalizer is $G$), and using the known result for normal subgroups, we can fill in the last pair as well, and the result follows.

Comment: Hi Ted, I have a question about the induction steps. $G$ is a $p$-group and so $|G|=p^r$ for some $r\ge 1$. To apply the induction assumption, we need a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{r-1}$. How do we find such a subgroup? Thanks.

Comment: I have come up with a way to find such a subgroup. We know the center $Z$ of a (non-trivial) $p$-group is non-trivial, which implies the order of $Z$ is $p^s$ for some $1\leq s\leq r$. By Cauchy theorem, we can find a subgroup $K\leq Z$ such that $|K|=p$. Since $K\leq Z$, $K$ is normal in $G$. Therefore we can take quotient, i.e. $G/K$ is well-defined. Now $|G/K|=p^{r-1}$ and we can apply the induction assumption. The base case is $|G|=p$.

Answer (score 2):

**Note.** This is an easy consequence of the Sylow Theorems as well: given any finite group $G$, a prime $p$, and if $p^n$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$, then given any subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|H|=p^i$ with $i\lt n$, there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ that contains $H$ and has order $p^{i+1}$. That $H$ is normal in $K$ will follow because the index of $H$ in $K$ is the smallest prime that divides $K$. Applying this to the case of $G$ of order $p^n$ gives you the desired conclusion.

But if you are trying to prove this *in order* to prove the Sylow Theorems (or you don't know this version of the Sylow Theorems), you can prove it directly, for example, as follows:

Let $|G|=p^m$. We proceed by induction on $m$.

If $m=1$, then either $H$ is trivial and we can take $H_0=H$, $H_1=G$; or else $H=G$ and we can take $H_0=G$.

Assume the result is true for any group of order strictly less than $m$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

If $Z(G)\cap H$ is nontrivial, then consider $H/(H\cap Z(G))$ in $G/(H\cap Z(G))$. By induction, we can find a subnormal chain
$$\frac{H}{H\cap Z(G)} = H_0 \triangleleft H_1\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft H_n = \frac{G}{H\cap Z(G)}$$
with $|H_{i+1}/H_{i}|=p$. By the isomorphism theorems, there exist subgroups $\widehat{H_i}$ of $G$, with $\widehat{H_i}/(H\cap Z(G)) = H_i$, and we have $\widehat{H_i}\triangleleft \widehat{H_{i+1}}$, $[\widehat{H_{i+1}}:\widehat{H_i}] = [H_{i+1}:H_i]=p$, giving the desired chain
$$H = \widehat{H_0}\triangleleft \widehat{H_1} \triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft \widehat{H_n}=G.$$

If $Z(G)\cap H=\{1\}$, then let $g\in Z(G)$ be an element of order $p$ (always possible, since $Z(G)\neq\{1\}$). Let $H'=\langle H,g\rangle$. Then $H\triangleleft H'$, and $|H'/H| = p$. Now we have $H'\cap Z(G)\neq\{1\}$, so we can apply the previous case to $H'$ to obtain a chain:
$$H'=H_0\triangleleft H_1\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft H_n = G,$$ 
with $|H_{i+1}/H_i|=p$. Now we have:
$$H = H_{-1}\triangleleft H_0\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft H_n=G$$
as a chain with the properties we want.

Comment: Hi Magidin, here we have successfully found a subnormal chain. Can we find a normal chain with some modifications to your argument here? By a normal chain, I mean $H_i \triangleleft G$ for all $i$.

Comment: @SamWong No, since your initial group need not be normal in $G$. If you require the initial group to be normal, then trivially yes, by taking $G/H$, picking a central element of order $p$ to generate a normal subgroup of order $p$ in the quotient, and then repeating the argument.